# Django/AWS - An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set up my Django project to host static images on AWS S3 buckets, but when I try to upload an image via the Django admin panel I get the following error

[image]

These are my settings in Django

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'some_key' 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'some_key_aswell' 
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_name'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2'
```

Cors policy setup for the bucket

```
 [
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

The IAM role used by the machine (or container) on which your Django app runs needs the following IAM policy added:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "s3:GetObject",
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/<prefix>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

If your object is encypted, make sure that you also allow your IAM role to use the KMS key used to encrypt your object.

Comment: I already have the policy, but the issue still occurs. The bucket is set to us-east-2, but I have travelled in the last week and I'm across the world. Could this be causing the issue? being in different regions i mean.

Comment: Is your bucket encrypted? Usually when I see access denied for the `HeadObject` action it is because the IAM role has to correct access to the S3 bucket, but cannot get the objects because it does not have access to its encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

I went over and changed the Bucket policy to this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i faced same error once.I changed "Action": "s3:GetObject", to  "Action": "s3:*". its worked for me